# Automating game simulation, using previous results

Tags: function-construction

Based on [this question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1494480/what-is-the-optimal-strategy-in-the-factor-game), I would like to simulate a game whereby player $2$ enters a number, so as to test the strategy. The basis for this is the [**factor game** online here](https://illuminations.nctm.org/Activity.aspx?id=4134).

```
rf[list_, n_] := With[{aa = If[MemberQ[list[[1]], n] == False, list[[1]], 
If[{n} == Select[list[[1]], MemberQ[Divisors[n], #] &], list[[1]], 
Complement[list[[1]], Divisors[n]]]]}, {aa, If[MemberQ[list[[1]], n] == 
False, {0}, If[{n} == Select[list[[1]], MemberQ[Divisors[n], #] &], {0}, 
{n}]], If[MemberQ[list[[1]], n] == False, {0}, 
Complement[Select[list[[1]], MemberQ[Divisors[n], #] &], {n}]]}]

rf2[list_, n_] := With[{aa = If[MemberQ[list, n] == False, list, 
If[{n} == Select[list, MemberQ[Divisors[n], #] &], list, 
Complement[list, Divisors[n]]]]}, aa]

s1a[list_] := With[{bb = With[{aa = rf[{list, {}, {}}, #]}, 
Total@aa[[2]] - Total@aa[[3]]] & /@ list}, 
list[[Position[bb, Max@bb][[1, 1]]]]]

pnot = {4, 9, 25, 28, 29, 42, 52, 53, 54, 58, 59, 60, 61, 66, 77, 86, 102, 103, 104, 108, 109, 114, 115, 117, 122, 123, 161, 162, 176, 177, 182, 183, 184, 185, 187, 189, 194, 195, 210, 211, 216, 217, 221, 228, 229, 238, 239, 243, 245, 247, 248, 249, 273, 282, 283, 286, 287, 288, 289, 292, 293, 298, 310, 311, 312, 313, 324, 325, 330, 331, 333, 338, 339, 343, 344, 345, 350, 351, 354, 355, 363, 364, 365, 369, 374, 375, 376, 382, 383, 384, 385, 387, 391, 392, 395, 396, 397, 405, 407, 408, 409, 412, 413, 414, 415, 420, 421, 429, 432, 433, 436, 437, 442, 443, 444, 445, 452, 453, 458, 466, 467, 477, 482, 487, 488};

opening[nn_] := If[nn > 4, With[{choice = If[MemberQ[pnot, #], 
Max@Select[Range@#, OddQ@# == True && PrimeOmega@# == 2 &], 
Prime@PrimePi@#] &@nn, prevList = Range@nn}, {{choice}, 
DeleteCases[#, choice] &@ Complement[prevList, rf2[prevList, choice]], 
rf2[prevList, choice]}], If[nn == 4, {{4}, {1, 2}, {3}}, "No game"]]

p2[nn_] := With[{choice = nn, prevList = %[[3]]}, {{choice}, 
DeleteCases[#, choice] &@ Complement[prevList, rf2[prevList, choice]], 
rf2[prevList, choice]}]

p1[] := With[{choice = s1a[%[[3]]], prevList = %[[3]]}, {{choice}, 
DeleteCases[#, choice] &@ Complement[prevList, rf2[prevList, choice]], 
rf2[prevList, choice]}]
```

by playing *eg* a simulated game on a $4\times 4$ board, I can do so by repeatedly copying and pasting the following, where `p2` is chosen by the player as a test of the strategy:

```
opening@16

(*
{{13}, {1}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16}}
*)
```

player two can then enter a number:

```
p2@15
p1[]

(*
{{15}, {3, 5}, {2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16}}
{{10}, {2}, {4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 14, 16}}
*)
```

and step `2` can be repeated until the game ends.

However, I would like to automate the process a liitle (maybe with popup windows? so that copying and pasting is not necessary. Also, I would ultimately be able to add up `p1` and `p2`'s scores at the end (without having to resort to copying and pasting and list manipulation.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Are game internals relevant? What do you need the popup for? Can't you just put the play inside `Do` loop or `Nest`?

Comment: @Kuba unsure how I would do that without having pre-chosen numbers for `p2`.